# In AWS Elastic Beanstalk, how to change parameter of php.ini

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, php-ini

I am running a website using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. In AWS Elastic Beanstalk, the default upload_max_filesize in php.ini is limited to 2M. I want to increase the upload_max_filesize to 20M. I do the following thing and 'Upload and Deploy' EBS by  uploading the new application source codes with the new  99my_php_ini_change.config.  But it does not automatically create the /etc/php.d/zzz_my_own_php.ini. I also 
'Create New Application' using Elastic Beanstalk, but I did not see the file /etc/php.d/zzz_my_own_php.ini was successfully created either.

Where is the error?

I thing I did was:

put file  99my_php_ini_change.config inside folder .ebextensions  under application root.

99my_php_ini_change.config   contains :

```
 files:   
    "/etc/php.d/zzz_my_own_php.ini" :

      mode: "000644"
      owner: root
      group: root
      content: |
          upload_max_filesize=20M
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any error messages in the log file at `/var/log/eb-activity.log`? You can view the full log file by doing an `eb ssh`, or you can retrieve it through the EB console or from the command-line using `eb logs`. If there are any errors, please show your log file here.

Also, YAML files are very sensitive to whitespace. You might try the following instead (notice the two spaces per indent level, lack of space before the colon, and lack of newline):

```
files:  
  "/etc/php.d/zzz_my_own_php.ini": 
     mode: "000644"
     owner: root
     group: root
     content: |
       upload_max_filesize=20M
```